# Limit amount of pages shown in pagination within wp_query

Tags: posts, wp-query, pages, pagination

I've got a query that looks like this:

```
$args = array (
    'post_type'              => $postType,
    'paged'                  => $paged,
    'pagination'             => true,
    'posts_per_page'         => '10',
    'order'                  => 'DESC',
    'orderby'                => 'date',
);

// The Query
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) {
        $wp_query->the_post();

            // post stuff

    }
} else { 
    // no posts 
}

pagination($additional_loop->max_num_pages); wp_reset_postdata(); wp_reset_query();
```

I've also got some custom pagination that in functions.php that looks like this:

```
function pagination($pages = '', $range = 4)
{  
     $showitems = ($range * 2)+1;  

     global $paged;
     if(empty($paged)) $paged = 1;

     if($pages == '')
     {
         global $wp_query;
         $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
         if(!$pages)
         {
             $pages = 1;
         }
     }   

     if(1 != $pages)
     {
         echo "<div class=\"pagination\"><span>Page ".$paged." of ".$pages."</span>";
         if($paged > 2 && $paged > $range+1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link(1)."'>&laquo; First</a>";
         if($paged > 1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged - 1)."'>&lsaquo; Previous</a>";

         for ($i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++)
         {
             if (1 != $pages &&( !($i >= $paged+$range+1 || $i <= $paged-$range-1) || $pages <= $showitems ))
             {
                 echo ($paged == $i)? "<span class=\"current\">".$i."</span>":"<a href='".get_pagenum_link($i)."' class=\"inactive\">".$i."</a>";
             }
         }

         if ($paged < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href=\"".get_pagenum_link($paged + 1)."\">Next &rsaquo;</a>";  
         if ($paged < $pages-1 &&  $paged+$range-1 < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($pages)."'>Last &raquo;</a>";
         echo "</div>\n";
     }
}
```

Again, works great. The only thing I can't figure out is how to limit the actual number of *pages* that are returned. For example, I might have 300 posts, paged into pages of 10. However, I only want to show a total of 30 posts split into 3 pages of 10.

Answer (score -1):

Change your query code to this:

```
add_filter( 'post_limits', 'my_post_limits' );

// The Query
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );

remove_filter( 'post_limits', 'my_post_limits' );
```

In your theme/functions.php, add this:

```
function my_post_limits( $limit, $query ) {

    return 'LIMIT 0, 30';

}
```

Comment: Interesting but not working in afraid! The pagination still lists out all of the pages and they all contain the same 30 posts.

Comment: Try using a 'normal' approach to pagination: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links